# Is it possible to call Delphi method with variable number of arguments from IActiveScript?

Tags: javascript, delphi, scripting

I'm using Delphi 2006 and [psvActiveScript](http://sourceforge.net/projects/psvlib/files/psvActiveScript/).

Example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, 
  ObjComAuto, ComObj, psvActiveScript;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnExecute: TButton;
    procedure btnExecuteClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ASWError(Sender: TObject; Line, Pos: Integer; ASrc, ADescription: String);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ASW: TpsvActiveScriptWindow;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

type
  {$METHODINFO ON}
  TMySriptableClass = class(TObjectDispatch)
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Alert(msg: string);
    // THIS OR SOMETHING SIMILAR NOT POSSIBLE? **********************
    function FnWithVarNumOfArgs(const args: array of string): string;
    // **************************************************************
  end;
  {$METHODINFO OFF}

constructor TMySriptableClass.Create;
begin inherited Create(Self, False); end;

procedure TMySriptableClass.Alert(msg: string);
begin ShowMessage(msg); end;

function TMySriptableClass.FnWithVarNumOfArgs(const args: array of string): string;
begin Result := 'OK'; end;


procedure TForm1.btnExecuteClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyObj: TMySriptableClass;
begin
  ASW := TpsvActiveScriptWindow.Create(self);
  ASW.ScriptLanguage := 'JScript';
  ASW.OnError := ASWError;

  MyObj := TMySriptableClass.Create;
  ASW.AddNamedItem('MyObj', MyObj);

  try
    ASW.Execute(
      'MyObj.Alert("Warning: Here comes Error");'+
      'MyObj.FnWithVarNumOfArgs("1","2","3")'
    );
  finally
    ASW.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ASWError(Sender: TObject; Line, Pos: Integer; ASrc, ADescription: String);
begin Showmessage(ADescription + ': ' + ASrc); end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[...]
uses
  activex, objcomauto, comobj;

type
  {$METHODINFO ON}
  TMySriptableClass = class(TObjectDispatch)
  public
    [...]
    function FnWithVarNumOfArgs(const args: OleVariant): string;
    [...]


function TMySriptableClass.FnWithVarNumOfArgs(const args: OleVariant): string;
var
  dispParams: activex.DISPPARAMS;
  vtRet, Element: OleVariant;
  Enum: IEnumVARIANT;
  Fetched: LongWord;
begin
  if TVarData(args).VType = varDispatch then begin
    OleCheck(IDispatch(args).Invoke(DISPID_NEWENUM, GUID_NULL,
                                    LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,
                                    dispParams, @vtRet, nil, nil));
    Enum := IUnknown(vtRet) as IEnumVARIANT;
    while (Enum.Next(1, Element, Fetched) = S_OK) do
      ShowMessage(Element);
  end;

  Result := 'OK';
end;


    [...]
    ASW.Execute('var myArray=["myarg1", 5, true];' +
                'MyObj.FnWithVarNumOfArgs(myArray);');
    [...]
```

Comment: Thank you. It works great. If possible, I would prefer not to change JScript part from Fn("1","2") to Fn(["1","2"]). If nobody came up with superior solution, I would accept your answer.

Comment: @A. Bonic - I believe you *have* to construct an array on the script side, without an array there's no way to pass an indefinite number of elements. BTW, I think the above would only work with a single dimensional array..

Answer (score 1):

The way you have set it up now, you would need to pass in an array of string since you declared the parameter as such. <strike>In Delphi itself that could be done using</strike>

```
MyObj.FnWithVarNumOfArgs(Array("1","2","3"))
```

Which would create a dynamic arry with the given values and then pass it to FnWithVarNumOfArgs.

From a scripting language <strike>Delphi's Array function certainly won't be available and</strike> you would need to do something clever with pointers, and I have no clue whether you could even get that to work.

Possibly your best bet is to use what is known as Variant Open Array Parameters.

From the help: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Variant_Open_Array_Parameters

> Variant open array parameters allow
>   you to pass an array of differently
>   typed expressions to a single
>   procedure or function. To define a
>   routine with a variant open array
>   parameter, specify array of const as
>   the parameter's type. Thus
>
> procedure DoSomething(A: array of
>   const);
>
> declares a procedure called
>   DoSomething that can operate on
>   heterogeneous arrays.
>
> The array of const construction is
>   equivalent to array ofTVarRec.
>   TVarRec, declared in the System unit,
>   represents a record with a variant
>   part that can hold values of integer,
>   Boolean, character, real, string,
>   pointer, class, class reference,
>   interface, and variant types.
>   TVarRec's VType field indicates the
>   type of each element in the array.
>   Some types are passed as pointers
>   rather than values; in particular,
>   strings are passed as Pointer and must
>   be typecast to string.

Comment: I don't quite get `MyObj.FnWithVarNumOfArgs(Array("1","2","3"))`. First, surely you mean `'` and not `"`? Anyhow, is `Array` a function that takes three strings and return a string array (that you have to write yourself)? What is "Delphi's Array function"?

Comment: @Andreas: oh deng, you caught me out. Yes, of course in Delphi the double quotes should be single. And the Array funtion is something that keeps getting into my mind, but should be ArrayOf and isn't in the VCL, but something we coded ourselves to circumvent the hassles of const and dynamic arrays, open array parameters and the like. Editing...

Comment: The JScript error message is the same ("Object doesn't support this property or method") with method declared as FnWithVarNumOfArgs(const args: array of const).

Comment: Does this psvActiveScript have any documentation? Would it help if you added a JavaScript tag to the question?

Comment: No documentation at all. It's just one file, about 600 LOC, mostly interfaces. There is a link on the top.

Comment: Clutching at straws here: try `var args: array of const` in case this is a bad case of messing up passing stuff by value or by reference...

Comment: @A. Bonic What types can you pass? Can you pass arrays or lists?

Comment: Strings, integers, floats as arguments works OK. Arrays only like this: MyObj.Test(new Array("1","2","3")) -> procedure Test(arr: Variant). Method is successfully called, but I don't know how to extract members. VarType(arr) is dispatch in this case. It's messy.

Comment: @Andreas: Ah, see, `new Array()` is what my mind try to make me write, but got all screwed up... :-) But wouldn't have worked with `args: array of string` anyway.

Comment: @A. Bonic: aren't all variants dispatch? Have a look through the AdoDB, DBClient, Provider for examples of converting to/from varArray. IE from the MidReg (PropertyEditors) unit `if VarIsArray(Data) then    for i := 0 to VarArrayHighBound(Data, 1) do    Proc(Data[i]);`

Comment: I'm not in position to test anything right now, but doubt it's that simple. varArray - Indicates a Variant array. varDispatch - Reference to an Automation object (an IDispatch interface pointer). See Sertac Akyuz's answer.